# How to get the id of a button in a listview

Tags: java, android

I have a customized widget with a textview and a button. My list view contains a list of the customized widget. I want to know on which button there is clicked. 
Like in Facebook each post has a react button and when you click on it you go to a specific page.

Comment: [Try this](http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_layxkurNJE1qzpwi0o1_500.jpg)

Comment: if your are created custom adapter then you can get there only id of the button.

Comment: @Allu thnx, indeed i had to use a custom adapter that extends from the BaseAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to create custom list. You can create a holder class to hold the your button and textview object. this will helpful for you to detect button click using holder class.

```
 class MyAdpter extends ArrayAdapter
        {

            int layout;
            ArrayList<Data> arr;
            Context con;

            public MyAdpter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Data> objects) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

                layout=textViewResourceId;
                arr= objects;
                con=context;
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final ViewHolder  holder=new ViewHolder();
                if(convertView==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView=inflator.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                    holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    holder.btn=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

                }



                holder.btn.setText("Data");
                holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(con, ""+holder.btn.getText(), 800).show();

                    }
                });

                holder.tv.setText("DATA");


                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return super.getCount();
            }

        }
        static class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView tv;
            Button btn;
        }
```

Comment: Thanx, I have used a class that extends the BaseAdapter and it works!